# Como posso pegar um EntityManager a partir de uma org.hibernate.Session

Tags: java, hibernate, session, persistência

Trabalho com o hibernate usando Session.

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    // A SessionFactory is set up once for an application
    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            return new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("Criação inicial do objeto SessionFactory falhou. Erro: " + e);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Usando como padrão a fabrica de sessão

```
public static ProdutoDAO criarProdutoDAO() {
        ProdutoDAOImpl produtoDAOImpl = new ProdutoDAOImpl();
        produtoDAOImpl.setSession(HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession());
        return produtoDAOImpl;
}
```

Criando assim minha sessão para os meus DAOs...

```
public class PedidoDAOImpl implements PedidoDAO {

    private Session session;

    public Session getSession() {
        return session;
    }

    public void setSession(Session session) {
        this.session = session;
    }
    ...
}
```

Mas dentro do DAO passei a ter a necessidade de utilizar um EntityManager para criar uma consulta personalizada onde me retorna uma lista de objeto não mapeado no hibernate...

Pegar uma Session de uma EntityManager já achei.

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
```

Mas pegar uma EntityManager de uma Session ainda não.

Gostaria de saber se é possível transformar, recuperar ou até mesmo criar uma EntityManager a partir de uma Session.

Desde já um muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

É necessário criar o EntityManagerFactory a partir do Hibernate/JPA.

Mas qual a necessidade de usar o EntityManager? O Session provê tudo que você precisa e ainda com mais funções.

Mas seria algo como:

```
EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("entidade");

EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();
```

Mas se for só por causa de uma consulta em SQL puro é possível fazer pela Session. Basta usar algo como:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("select colunas from tabela");
```

Comment: Na verdade sempre que procurei sobre consultas personalizadas encontrei o comando query.getResultList() então estava tentando utilizar o EntityManager para carregar a lista. Pois já tinha tentado carregar session e não tinha conseguido. Mas agora consegui com List<Object[]> result = query.list(). Muito obrigado.